# getting message **sharing failed please try again** in ionic app when I try to share link via whatsapp

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Explanation -:** 
 1. I am working on ionic project where I am trying to share link via whatsapp

2. I have used `shareViaWhatsApp(message, image, url)` function from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/
3. I have followed all the steps looking into the doc given by Ionic
4. But **PROBLEM** is -:

   When I am trying to share link via whatsapp window opens but it gives a message       **sharing failed please try again** 
   then whatsapp window closed , **and sharing failed**

I am putting code below -:

```
  shareViaWhatsapp(){
    console.log('invitewhatsapp');
    let message = 'Abcd';
    //let image = 'sdfgbdh.jpg';
    let url = "www.facebook.com";
    this.socialShare
      .shareViaWhatsApp(message,url,null)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('success');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Error');
      });
  }
```

html ->

```
<button ion-fab (click)="shareViaWhatsapp()"><ion-icon name="logo-whatsapp"></ion-icon></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is for the image and the third is for URL. Replace your code with this one:

```
this.socialShare
  .shareViaWhatsApp("Abcd",undefined,"www.facebook.com")
  .then(() => {
    console.log('success');
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log('Error');
  });
```

[More info about share via whatsapp](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/#shareViaWhatsApp)